# Kendo Ui Grid Save Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo ui grid for save the data. For Grid i am using Inline edit but my save button is not in individual row, grid data will save on one common button. My issue is below.

I have lots of row in grid like **60 to 100** when I am pressing the save button that grid will loop of all the row which have **(means loop will 60 to 100 times)**.

I want below scenario :

If I edit any 2 to 3 rows or 10 to 20 rows out of 100 and if I press the save button then only that edited row is update not all row. My code for save grid and binding of grid is as below. Please let me know if anyone find any solution.

```
// Bind Grid
    function MakeGridFromXML(data) {
        var div = document.getElementById("divValidationPlans");
        div.style.display = "block";
        if (data.length == 0) {
            var customFieldString = "<Fields>" +
            "<Field Id=\"TRTitle\" Title=\"TR Title\" Type=\"Text\" Value=\"\" class='k-textbox' />" +
            "<Field Id=\"TestType\" Title=\"Test Type\" Type=\"SingleSelect\" Value=\"\" />" +
            "<Field Id=\"TestProcedure\" Value=\"\" Title=\"Test Procedure\" Type=\"SingleSelect\" />" +
            "<Field Id=\"TestObjectives\" Value=\"\" Title=\"Test Objectives\" Type=\"Text\" /></Fields>";

    data.push({ "CustomFields": customFieldString, "TestObjectives": "" });
}
$("#grdTest").html("");
var fieldSchema = [];
var columnSchema = [];
columnSchema.push({
    field: "",
    width: "30px",
    template: "<input id='chkDelete' type='checkbox' />",
});


var counter = 0;
$.each(data, function (index) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    var isInsertUpdate = false;
    var xmldoc = $.parseXML(data[index].CustomFields);
    var $xml = $(xmldoc);
    var jsonStr = '{';
    $xml.find("Fields").find("Field").each(function () {
        jsonStr = jsonStr + '"' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + '":{';
        jsonStr = jsonStr + '"Title":"' + $(this).attr("Title") + '",';
        jsonStr = jsonStr + '"Value":"' + $(this).attr("Value") + '",';
        jsonStr = jsonStr + '"Id":"' + $(this).attr("Id") + '"},';

        if (counter == 1) {
            var type = $(this).attr("Type");
            switch (type) {
                case 'SingleSelect':
                    if ($(this).attr("Id") != 'TestType' &&
                        $(this).attr("Id") != 'TestProcedure') {
                        var fieldXmlString = '';
                        $.ajax({
                            url: GetApiUrl('CustomFieldApi/GetCustomField'),
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: { id: $(this).attr("Id") },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (resultxml) {
                                fieldXmlString = resultxml.FieldDefinition;
                            }

                        });
                        columnSchema.push({
                            field: $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value",
                            title: $(this).attr("Title"),
                            width: "128px",
                            template: '<label title="#= ' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + '.Value#">' + "#=" + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value#" + '</label>',
                            editor: function (container, options) {
                                isInsertUpdate = true;
                                var $rowxml = $(fieldXmlString),
                                    isSystemField = $rowxml.attr("IsSystem");
                                if (isSystemField == '1') {
                                    var bindSource = $rowxml.attr("bindSource"),
                                        bindField = $rowxml.attr("bindField");
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: GetApiUrl('customfieldapi/GetCfSourceToBind'),
                                        type: 'GET',
                                        data: { BindSource: bindSource, BindField: bindField },
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        async: false,
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoComboBox({
                                                autoBind: false,
                                                dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                                    data: data,
                                                }),
                                                minLength: 1,
                                                filter: "startswith",
                                                suggest: true
                                            }).data("kendoDropDownList");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else {
                                    $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoComboBox({
                                        autoBind: false,
                                        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                            data: fieldXmlString,
                                            schema: {
                                                type: "xml",
                                                data: "/Field/Option",
                                                model: {
                                                    fields: {
                                                        displayValue: "@Text",
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },

                                        }),
                                        dataTextField: "displayValue",
                                        dataValueField: "displayValue",
                                        minLength: 1,
                                        filter: "startswith",
                                        suggest: true
                                    }).data("kendoDropDownList");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else if ($(this).attr("Id") == 'TestType') {
                        columnSchema.push({
                            field: $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value",
                            title: $(this).attr("Title"),
                            width: "128px",
                            editor: function (container, options) {
                                isInsertUpdate = true;
                                TestTypeEditor(container, options);
                            },
                            template: '<label title="#= ' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + '.Value#">' + "#=" + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value#" + '</label>',
                        });
                    }
                    else if ($(this).attr("Id") == 'TestProcedure') {
                        columnSchema.push({
                            field: $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value",
                            title: $(this).attr("Title"),
                            width: "128px",
                            editor: TestProcedureEditor,
                            template: '<label title="#= ' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + '.Value#">' + "#=" + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value#" + '</label>',
                        });
                    }
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    columnSchema.push({
                        field: $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value",
                        title: $(this).attr("Title"),
                        width: "128px",
                        template: '<label title="#= ' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + '.Value#">' + "#=" + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value#" + '</label>',
                        editor: function (container, options) {
                            $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + "" + '" maxlength="10">').appendTo(container).kendoDatePicker({
                                format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                change: function (e) {
                                    var displayDate = e.sender._oldText;
                                    $("#grdTest").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(this.element.closest("tr")).set(options.field, displayDate);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case "Number":
                    columnSchema.push({
                        field: $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value",
                        title: $(this).attr("Title"),
                        width: "128px",
                        template: '<label title="#= ' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + '.Value#">' + "#=" + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value#" + '</label>',
                        editor: function (container, options) {
                            $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + "" + '">').appendTo(container).kendoNumericTextBox({
                                min: 0,
                                change: function (e) {
                                    var displayData = e.sender._old;
                                    $("#grdTest").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(this.element.closest("tr")).set(options.field, displayData);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case "Text":
                    columnSchema.push({
                        field: $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value",
                        title: $(this).attr("Title"),
                        width: "128px",
                        template: '<label title="#= ' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + '.Value#">' + "#=" + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value#" + '</label>',
                        editor: '<input class="k-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value:' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value" + '" style="display:block; width:80%;" />'
                    });
                    break;
                    //case "CheckBoxList":
                    //    var fieldXmlString = '';
                    //    $.ajax({
                    //        url: GetApiUrl('CustomFieldApi/GetCustomField'),
                    //        type: 'GET',
                    //        data: { id: $(this).attr("Id") },
                    //        dataType: 'json',
                    //        success: function (resultxml) {
                    //            fieldXmlString = resultxml;
                    //        }

                    //    });
                    //    columnSchema.push({
                    //        field: $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value",
                    //        title: $(this).attr("Title"),
                    //        width: "128px",
                    //        template: "#=" + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value#",
                    //        editor: function (container, options) {
                    //        }
                    //    });
                    //    break;
                default:
                    columnSchema.push({
                        field: $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value",
                        title: $(this).attr("Title"),
                        width: "128px",
                        template: '<label title="#= ' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + '.Value#">' + "#=" + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value#" + '</label>',
                        editor: '<textarea rows="2" data-bind="value:' + $(this).attr("Title").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') + ".Value" + '" style="text-overflow:ellipsis; display:block; width:80%; height:100%; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;color:black"></textarea>'
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    var TestReuqestTitle = data[index].TRTitle == undefined ? "" : data[index].TRTitle.replace(/\r?\n/g, "");
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"CustomFields":{"Id":"CustomFields","Title":"CustomFields","Value":"' + data[index].CustomFields.replace(/\"/g, "\'") + '"},';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"VPId":{"Id":"VPId","Title":"VPId","Value":"' + data[index].ValidationPlanId + '"},';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"isInsertUpdate":{"Id":"isInsertUpdateId","Title":"isInsertUpdateId","Value":"' + isInsertUpdate + '"},';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"TRTitle":{"Id":"TRTitle","Title":"TRTitle","Value":"' + TestReuqestTitle + '"},';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"TestTypeId":{"Id":"TestTypeId","Title":"TestTypeId","Value":"' + data[index].TestTypeId + '"},';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"TestObjectives":{"Id":"TestObjectives","Title":"TestObjectives","Value":"' + data[index].TestObjectives + '"},';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '"TestProcedureId":{"Id":"TestProcedureId","Title":"TestProcedureId","Value":"' + data[index].TestProcedureId + '"}';
    jsonStr = jsonStr + '}';

    fieldSchema.push($.parseJSON(jsonStr));
});

$("#grdTest").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: fieldSchema,
        schema: {
            total: function (result) {
                var totalCount = result.length;
                return totalCount;
            }

        },
        pageSize: 10
    }),
    columns: columnSchema,
    editable: true,
    filterable: true,
    pageable: {
        input: true,
        numeric: false
    },
    sortable: {
        mode: "multiple",
        allowUnsort: true
    },
    resizable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    toolbar: [
        {
            name: 'ToolbarButtons',
            template: '#= ToolbarButtons()#'
        }
    ],

});

}

//Save Grid Data.
    function SaveChanges() {
    var grid = $("#grdTest").data("kendoGrid");
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.dataSource._data.length; i++) {
        $("#grdTest").busyIndicator(true); // show
        if (grid.dataSource._data[i].TestTypeId.Value != 'undefined' && grid.dataSource._data[i].TestTypeId.Value != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' && grid.dataSource._data[i].TestTypeId.Value != "" &&
    grid.dataSource._data[i].TestProcedureId.Value != 'undefined' && grid.dataSource._data[i].TestProcedureId.Value != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' && grid.dataSource._data[i].TestProcedureId.Value != "") {

        var strFieldXml = grid.dataSource._data[i].CustomFields.Value;
        var fieldXmldoc = $.parseXML(strFieldXml);
        var $fieldXml = $(fieldXmldoc);
        grid.dataSource._data[i].forEach(function (field) {
            if (field.Title != 'CustomFields' && field.Title != 'VPId' && field.Title != 'TestTypeId' && field.Title != 'TestProcedureId') {
                $fieldXml.find("Fields").find("Field").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr("Id") == field.Id) {
                        $(this).attr("Value", field.Value.toString().replace(/["'<>\r\n]/g, ""));
                    }
                });

            }
        });


        grid.dataSource._data[i].CustomFields.Value = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($fieldXml[0]);
        var vp = {
            VMId: $('#hdnVMId').val(),
            ValidationPlanId: grid.dataSource._data[i].VPId.Value,
            TRTitle: grid.dataSource._data[i].TRTitle.Value,
            TestTypeId: grid.dataSource._data[i].TestTypeId.Value,
            TestProcedureId: grid.dataSource._data[i].TestProcedureId.Value,
            TestObjectives: grid.dataSource._data[i].TestObjectives.Value.replace(/["'<>\r\n]/g, ""),
            CustomFields: grid.dataSource._data[i].CustomFields.Value,
        };
        if (grid.dataSource._data[i].VPId.Value != 'undefined' && grid.dataSource._data[i].VPId.Value != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' && grid.dataSource._data[i].VPId.Value != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: GetApiUrl('ValidationPlanApi/Put'),
                type: 'PUT',
                data: JSON.stringify(vp),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: LoadValidationPlans,
                async: false,
            });
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: GetApiUrl('ValidationPlanApi/Post'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(vp),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: LoadValidationPlans,
                async: false,
            });
        }
    }

}
$("#grdTest").busyIndicator(false); // hide
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below code while grid is binding. You have to take one javascript Array and push your updated value (basically this automatically done by grid while you add below code).

Now user that array in my case (updatedVPID) for save detail. At save function loop that array and go ahead with you logic.

```
dataBound: function (e) {
            var grid = $("#grdTest").data("kendoGrid");
            $(grid.tbody).on("click", "td", function (e) {
                var item = grid.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                    updatedVPID.push(item);
                    var uniqueIds = [];
                    $.each(updatedVPID, function (i, el) {
                        if ($.inArray(el, uniqueIds) === -1) uniqueIds.push(el);
                    });
                    updatedVPID = uniqueIds;                    
            });
        },
```